# Making my code more readable

Tags: python, list

So I want to make my output code to be more readable and I need some help as I'm unsure of what to do, as of right now it outputs this:

```
OrderedDict([('David', 63), ('Adamz', 10), ('Daloe', 1), ('Avid', 1), ('Aaaab', 1), ('Dlo', 1), ('D', 0), ('Da', 0), ('N', 0), ('Adz', 0)])
```

I'd like to remove the `OrderedDict` and make it print it out a list like so:

```
David: 63
Adamz: 10
Daloe: 1
Avid: 1
```

This is the code:

```
def alphabetically(some_data):
    return OrderedDict(
        (k, some_data[k]['scores'])
        for k in sorted(some_data)
    )


def by_score(some_data, descending=True):
    return OrderedDict(
        (k, sum(some_data[k]['scores']))
        for k in sorted(some_data,
                        key=lambda k: sum(some_data[k]['scores']),
                        reverse=descending)
    )


def by_average(some_data, descending=True):
    def average(scores):
        return float(sum(scores)) / len(scores)
    return OrderedDict(
        (k, average(some_data[k]['scores']))
        for k in sorted(some_data,
                        key=lambda k: average(some_data[k]['scores']),
                        reverse=descending)
```

This is how and where it outputs the code from:

```
data = defaultdict(dict)
with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        name, score = line.split(' : ')
        scores = data[name].get('scores', [])
        scores.append(int(score))
        data[name]['scores'] = scores

if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view the previous results from your class: "):
    while True:                                                                  
        selection= input('Do you wish to view the results in: Alphabetical order (A),''\n                                   scores highest to lowest (B),''\n                                   or average score highest to lowest?(C): '
                         )
        if selection not in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
            print ("Error, type in A, B or C.")
            continue
        if selection == 'A':
            print (alphabetically(data))                                         
        elif selection == 'B':
            print (by_score(data))                                               
        elif selection == 'C':
            print (by_average(data))                                             
        break                                                                    

else:
    input ("Press any key to exit")
```

Comment: So you're actually asking how to make your _output_ readable, not your _code_? You said "code" then you said "output code" then you gave an example of output.

Comment: Ok, so... do that?

Comment: Lol, didn't realise, fixed @BarryTheHatchet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some formatted printing:

```
for key in my_ordered_dict:
    print "%s: %s" % (key, my_ordered_dict[key], )
```

If you're going to do this multiple times, it's worth creating a nice function that you can call.

```
def pretty_print_dict(my_dict):
    for key in my_dict:
        print "%s: %s" % (key, my_dict[key], )
```

Or for Python 3 you could try something like this:

```
def pretty_print_dict(my_dict):
    for key in my_dict:
        print('{0}: {1}'.format(key, my_dict[key]))
```

Then you call either of them like this:

```
if selection == 'A':
    pretty_print_dict(alphabetically(data))
```

Comment: I added in the function part and tried to run it after putting in the last bit in but I got a syntax error for the function. The speech mark was highlighted where it says print ""%s: %s"

Comment: Are you using Python 3 by any chance? I'll add an alternative

Comment: Yes, Python 3 is being used.

Comment: I've added a Python 3 version, though I haven't fully tested it. Full details of formatting and printing strings nicely in Python 3 are here: https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Did you want me to input something where it says 'key' in the function? Also, it says its a invalid syntax and highlights print 'pretty_print_dict'(alphabetically(data)) this time. ' '=highlighted red.

Comment: No, key is a variable to hold each key in the dict, so leave it as key! Have you added those ' marks? They shouldn't be there.

Comment: Oh and also, pretty_print_dict replaces the print in your original code!

Comment: I've edited the invocation of pretty_print_dict to make it clearer. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how you're outputting the function results, or even calling the functions, but why not just create a new function that wraps that call in a loop and prints the elements however you like?

Comment: @Draguno: My answer still applies.

Comment: @Draguno: Create a function that you can call. Pass it your arrays instead of just printing them out directly. Have that function print out the contents however you like. srowland showed you how.

Comment: This isn't an answer and did not help me in any shape or form, please if your criticizing my post, comment under the post.

Comment: @Draguno: Don't be so rude when people are spending their free time trying to help you.

Comment: That did not help me, i thought your answer was quite rude, it may come across as me being rude but I'm not.

Comment: Thank you, for your input, I just simply said that your answer was not helpful and instead found it quite rude. :)